# Custom Icon on ScriptableObject on Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I doing some items for my game make the development easier, I wish to add custom icons to my items, which are `ScriptableObjects`, how can I do this? I know the trick of put the icon on Gizmo folder with the same name as the script, but the icons should be different for different items which have the same script

Answer (score 1):

You can add a RawImage field to your scriptable object.

```
[SerializeField] RawImage imageIcon;
```

Edit to answer your additional question:

1. Create the new object with your scriptable object
2. Click on the newly created object
3. View inspector and click the icon:
   [image]
4. Click Other
5. Pick your image.

Additionally you can check out this asset package and create icons based on the data: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/asseticons-100547

Comment: this just allow me to use image, i wanna put icon on the scritptable object on project widow.

Comment: is just like this asset do, i was thinking it was a easier way to do this, your solution is good, but this just change the icon of the all scriptables object wich have the target script, i was looking for some to customise, different scriptable objects with the same code

Answer (score -1):

1. Create Field "icon" in your ScriptableObject sub class;
2. Create Custom Editor for your ScriptableObject sub class;
3. Create Target property in editor

```
    public StateMachine Target {
                get {
                    return this.target as StateMachine;
                }
        }
```

4. override this method

```
    public override Texture2D RenderStaticPreview(string assetPath, UnityEngine.Object[] subAssets, int width, int height) {


            Texture2D newIcon = new Texture2D(width, height);


            if (Target.icon != null) {
                EditorUtility.CopySerialized(Target.icon, newIcon);
                return newIcon;
            } else {

                Texture2D defaultCustomIcon = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/WinxProduction/Editor/Editor Default Resources/StateMachine Icon.png", typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;

                if (defaultCustomIcon != null) {




                   EditorUtility.CopySerialized(defaultCustomIcon, newIcon);

                    Target.icon=newIcon;

                    AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(newIcon,Target);

                    EditorUtility.SetDirty(Target);

                    return newIcon;
                }
            }

            return base.RenderStaticPreview(assetPath, subAssets, width, height);
        }
```

First time when Unity Loads will use default Icon and save for all custom sub class ScriptableObjects. If you want to have different icons then default you would create some function like this:

```
    protected void OnClickBrowseForNewIcon() {

                    string path=EditorUtility.OpenFilePanelWithFilters("Select icon","Assets",new string[]{"Icon files", "png",});

                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)){

                        Target.icon=AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(AssetDatabaseUtility.AbsoluteUrlToAssets(path));

                        EditorUtility.SetDirty(Target);

                    }
                }
```

Relative to absolute

```
    public static class AssetDatabaseUtility
        {

            public static string AbsoluteUrlToAssets(string absoluteUrl)
            {
                Uri fullPath = new Uri (absoluteUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
                Uri relRoot = new Uri (Application.dataPath, UriKind.Absolute);

                return relRoot.MakeRelativeUri (fullPath).ToString ();


            }
        }
```

Comment: The above solution works but only for the Inspector, it does not change the icon in the project window.